# C (cpp) extension in Python works on one machine but does not on the other

Tags: python

Sorry If this question is a bit vague, and might not be appropriate at all for stackoverflow, but I am just giving this a shot, maybe someone will have a clue as to what could be the reason or give ways to test, where the problem is.

I have a C (cpp?) extension which works fine on my 13.04 Lubuntu with gcc 4.7.3, python 2.7.4, numpy 1.7.1 but does not work in 12.04 Ubuntu with gcc 4.6.3, python 2.7.3, numpy 1.6.1 on another machine. It seems to build/install fine, but when I actually try to run the thing, it gives me a certain error:

```
TypeError: Array type 7 didn't match expected type -1
```

I do not want to spam you with the build codes, but I will include the two codes, which I think are the main. First is the cpp file

```
    #define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL j_sad_pyarray
    #include "Common/JAssert.h"
    #include "Python.h"
    #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
    #include "Common/JPythonCommon.h"

    extern "C" PyObject *sad_correlation(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
    {
        // inputs
        PyArrayObject *a, *b;       // list of coordinates for the input polygons (2d double numpy array)

        // parse the input arrays from *args
        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!O!", 
                &PyArray_Type, &a, 
                &PyArray_Type, &b))
        {
            PyErr_Format(PyErr_NewException((char*)"exceptions.TypeError", NULL, NULL), "Unable to parse array!");
            return NULL;
        }

        // We expect a and b to be two-dimensional double arrays.
        // The following constructors will check those requirements
        JPythonArray2D<double> window1(a);
        JPythonArray2D<double> window2(b);
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) return NULL;

    //  ALWAYS_ASSERT(window1.NDims() == 2);
    //  ALWAYS_ASSERT(window2.NDims() == 2);
        if ((window1.NDims() != 2) || (window1.NDims() != 2))
        {
            PyErr_Format(PyErr_NewException((char*)"exceptions.TypeError", NULL, NULL), "Expected two 2D arrays as parameters");
            return NULL;
        }

        int maxDX = window2.Dims()[0] - window1.Dims()[0];
        int maxDY = window2.Dims()[1] - window1.Dims()[1];
    //  ALWAYS_ASSERT(maxDX >= 0);
    //  ALWAYS_ASSERT(maxDY >= 0);
        if ((maxDX < 0) || (maxDY < 0))
        {
            PyErr_Format(PyErr_NewException((char*)"exceptions.TypeError", NULL, NULL), "Expected second array to be bigger than or equal to first array");
            return NULL;
        }

        npy_intp output_dims[2] = { maxDX+1, maxDY+1 };
        PyArrayObject *result = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_SimpleNew(2, output_dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
        JPythonArray2D<double> resultArray(result);

        // For every possible shift of 'a' relative to 'b', calculate the SAD
    //  printf("Array sizes %ldx%ld, %ldx%ld\n", window1.Dims()[0], window1.Dims()[1], window2.Dims()[0], window2.Dims()[1]);
        int w1Width = window1.Dims()[0];
        int w1Height = window1.Dims()[1];
        for (int dy = 0; dy <= maxDY; dy++)
            for (int dx = 0; dx <= maxDX; dx++)
            {
                int sad = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < w1Height; y++)
                    for (int x = 0; x < w1Width; x++)
                    {
                        // ***** is this the correct way round?
                        ALWAYS_ASSERT(window1[0].Dims()[0] == window1.Dims()[1]);
                        sad += abs(window1[x][y] - window2[x+dx][y+dy]);
                    }
                resultArray[dx][dy] = sad;  
    //          printf("Result[%d][%d] = %d\n", dx, dy, sad);       
            }
        return PyArray_Return(result);
    }


    /* Define a methods table for the module */

    static PyMethodDef corr_methods[] = {
        {"sad_correlation", sad_correlation, METH_VARARGS}, 
        {NULL,NULL} };



    /* initialisation - register the methods with the Python interpreter */

    extern "C" void initj_py_sad_correlation(void)
    {
        (void) Py_InitModule("j_py_sad_correlation", corr_methods);
        import_array();
    }
```

And the .py file:

```
# Run the following command:
#   python setup.py build; python setup.py install
# in order to compile and install the j_py_sad_correlation module
from j_py_sad_correlation import *
import numpy as N

a = N.random.randint(0, 100, (4,4))
b = N.random.randint(0, 100, (4,4))
print a
print b

sad_using_c_code = sad_correlation(a, b)
print sad_using_c_code

sad_using_python_code = N.zeros((b.shape[0] - a.shape[0] + 1, b.shape[1] - a.shape[1] + 1))
for z in range(sad_using_python_code.shape[1]):
    for q in range(sad_using_python_code.shape[0]):
        sad_using_python_code[q,z] = sum(sum(abs(a - b[q:q+a.shape[0], z:z+a.shape[1]])))
print sad_using_python_code

print "success if these values are both zero:", (sad_using_python_code - sad_using_c_code).max(), (sad_using_python_code - sad_using_c_code).min()
```

I am unable to update the gcc on this machine (whatever I do, I end up with the same one), do you think this could be a problem (i.e. the gcc version) ? Are there any ways to track the problem down ?

The part of the JPythonArray.h:

```
template<class Type> class JPythonArray1D : public JPythonArray<Type>
{
  public:
    JPythonArray1D(PyArrayObject *init) : JPythonArray<Type>(init, 1) { }
    JPythonArray1D(PyObject *init) : JPythonArray<Type>(init, 1) { }
    JPythonArray1D(Type *inData, npy_intp *inDims, npy_intp *inStrides) : JPythonArray<Type>(inData, 1, inDims, inStrides) { }

    Type &operator[](int i)     // Note we return a reference here, so that this can be used as an lvalue, e.g. my1DArray[0] = 1.0, or my2DArray[0][0] = 1.0;
    {
//      printf("Access element %d of %d\n", i, JPythonArray<Type>::dims[0]);
        ALWAYS_ASSERT(i < JPythonArray<Type>::dims[0]);
        return JPythonArray<Type>::data[i * JPythonArray<Type>::strides[0]];
    }

    Type &GetIndex_CanPromote(int i)
    {
        // Behaves like operator[], but if we have a single value in the array then returns that value regardless of i
        // This isn't ideal - it's a way of working around the fact that the object used to initialize this array may be a scalar value
        if (JPythonArray<Type>::dims[0] == 1)
            return JPythonArray<Type>::data[0];
        else
            return operator[](i);
    }
};

template<class Type> class JPythonArray2D : public JPythonArray<Type>
{
  public:
    JPythonArray2D(PyArrayObject *init) : JPythonArray<Type>(init, 2) { }
    JPythonArray2D(PyObject *init) : JPythonArray<Type>(init, 2) { }
    JPythonArray2D(Type *inData, npy_intp *inDims, npy_intp *inStrides) : JPythonArray<Type>(inData, 2, inDims, inStrides) { }

    JPythonArray1D<Type> operator[](int i)
    {
        // Could check that i is in range (check against dims[0])
        return JPythonArray1D<Type>(JPythonArray<Type>::data + JPythonArray<Type>::strides[0] * i, JPythonArray<Type>::dims + 1, JPythonArray<Type>::strides + 1);
    }
};

template<class Type> class JPythonArray3D : public JPythonArray<Type>
{
  public:
    JPythonArray3D(PyArrayObject *init) : JPythonArray<Type>(init, 3) { }
    JPythonArray3D(PyObject *init) : JPythonArray<Type>(init, 3) { }

    JPythonArray2D<Type> operator[](int i)
    {
        // Could check that i is in range (check against dims[0])
        return JPythonArray2D<Type>(JPythonArray<Type>::data + JPythonArray<Type>::strides[0] * i, JPythonArray<Type>::dims + 1, JPythonArray<Type>::strides + 1);
    }
};

template<class Type> JPythonArray2D<Type> PromoteTo2D(PyArrayObject *init)
{
    if (PyArray_NDIM(init) == 1)
    {
        npy_intp dims[2] = { 1, PyArray_DIMS(init)[0] };
        npy_intp strides[2] = { 0, PyArray_STRIDES(init)[0] / sizeof(Type) };
        return JPythonArray2D<Type>((Type *)PyArray_DATA(init), dims, strides);
    }
    else
    {
        // This could fail (if for example we are given a 3D array), but if that happens then a suitable error should be reported
        return JPythonArray2D<Type>(init);
    }
}
```

And the full JPythonArray.cpp:

```
#include "JPythonArray.h"

template<> int ArrayType<double>(void) { return NPY_DOUBLE; }
template<> int ArrayType<float>(void) { return NPY_FLOAT; }
template<> int ArrayType<int>(void) { return NPY_INT; }
```

Comment: Are you using the same Python and NumPy versions on both machines?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but you seem to be using C++ syntax (template syntax) inside an `extern "C"` block. Not sure if that's a good idea. (And how are you building the extension in the first place?)

Comment: Should have added this. I edited the question, but copy it here also:

13.04 Lubuntu with gcc 4.7.3, python 2.7.4, numpy 1.7.1 but does not work in 12.04 Ubuntu with gcc 4.6.3, python 2.7.3, numpy 1.6.1 on another machine.

I just Run the following command:
python setup.py build; python setup.py install

And have a folder build and Common with .cpp and .h files...But I doubt it is what you ask about how I build the extension.

Comment: You should be able to see whether gcc or g++ was used when running `setup.py build`. Also, is `JPythonArray2D` indeed a C++ template?

Comment: Whenever I get an error (if I modify something) it says it is a gcc error. Otherwise, it does not show up anywhere when running.

Interestingly I only have JPythonArray.h and .cpp, but inside it they have JPythonArray2D mentioned (I am not familiar with cpp, and I got this code made by someone else, I have added the probably relevant part of the .h file. in the original question).

Do you think the code is the problem (i.e. the C, cpp issue ?) I wonder why it works fine on my other machine...

Comment: Maybe it has some bytecode on one machine that you're accidentally copying to the other?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by that ? I am using the same files (a copy of the other) on both machines.

Comment: What @rogerdpack suggests is that may be some *.pyc or *.pyo files are being unintentionally copied between machines. I would add if you are sure that *.o files are not transfered as well.

Comment: Is one of the machines 64 bit and the other 32?